# Is MySQL release_lock() Blocking?

Tags: mysql, go

I'm running MySQL:

```
~/g/profile> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

My Go application is [performing some schema migrations](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate), which starts with [`SELECT GET_LOCK()`](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/blob/master/database/mysql/mysql.go#L227) and then executes a bunch of DDL and other statements, followed by [`SELECT RELEASE_LOCK()`](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/blob/4e593fd2a9dd43d185dcf2793243b2ccea042c29/database/mysql/mysql.go#L252).  All of these queries are executed on the same connection.

I'm experiencing a scenario where the migration driver returns a success (lock has now been released) and yet immediately subsequent SQL calls see a picture of the database which is only partly migrated.  Calls a few ms later see the fully migrated schema.

I have read through [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html#function_release-lock) on these MySQL functions.  I understand that these create/destroy an "advisory lock" which has no power to prevent concurrent access to data except when two applications use the same name for the lock.

My question is, is it possible for `RELEASE_LOCK()` to return before other statement(s) executed with the same connection, or before such statements completely take effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you run:

```
GET_LOCK()
...some DDL statements...
RELEASE_LOCK()
```

And these are run serially on a single thread, then no, it's not possible for RELEASE_LOCK() to run before the DDL statements are finished.

In fact, the DDL statements themselves are blocking. They don't return until the DDL is complete.

I suspect you have one of the following going on:

- Some of the DDL statements did not succeed, but you're not checking for their error status.
- You are trying to use multiple threads, and you somehow allowed the RELEASE_LOCK() to run before the DDL thread is finished.

Comment: Accepted -- `it's not possible for RELEASE_LOCK() to run before the DDL statements are finished` answers my question. Your second guess was correct; the problem turned out to to be subtle, concurrent test execution: https://medium.com/@xcoulon/how-to-avoid-parallel-execution-of-tests-in-golang-763d32d88eec

Answer (score 0):

Your Session probably ended early because

> A lock obtained with GET_LOCK() is released explicitly by executing RELEASE_LOCK() or implicitly when **your session terminates (either normally or abnormally)**. Locks obtained with GET_LOCK() are not released when transactions commit or roll back.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  However, if session == connection and all of these statements are run on the same connection I don't see how my session could have ended?

Comment: Your DDL ended prematurely, but as you wanted to know, if it is possible, so yes a lock can be release. I think that your problem lies in your data and as always in that case it will be a Payne to find it.